# Сложные сценарии в Яндекс.Танк

Tags: яндекс-танк

Можно ли в ЯТ задать некую бизнес логику:

1. ветвления сценариев;
2. сложные сценарии, допускающие вложения одного в другой;
3. проверка ответов от сервера;
4. параметризацию скриптов (например подстановка значений переменных из заранее определенного пула).

Вопрос интересует в контексте сравнения HP Perfomance center и Яндекс.Танк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для сценарных тестов в ЯТ используется python сценарии для BFG либо jMeter.
Оба эти варианта покрывают пункты 1..4

На Pycon 2017 был доклад про использование BFG - http://pycon.ru/2017/program/content/Mirgorodskaya/

Сравнить с  HP Perfomance center не могу, не пользовался им.

Comment: Спасибо. По ссылке кратко описан ответ на вопрос.